# How does polymorphism work with member variables in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning about polymorphism in C++ and am learning about the `virtual` function specifier. Since the `virtual` specifier forces the program to use the child class's functions, why does it not force the function to use the child class's member variables? Is there a way to do this in C++?

I have tried running the following code with the following classes:

```
class Student
{
public:
    virtual int returnGPA()
    {
        return gpa;
    }
private:
    int gpa = 3;
};

class HonorStudent : public Student
{
public:
    virtual int returnGPA() override
    {
        return gpa;
    }

private:
    int gpa = 4;

};

int main()
{

    Student s = Student();
    Student h = HonorStudent();
    std::cout << s.returnGPA() << std::endl;
    std::cout << h.returnGPA() << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I expected the output of the function to be

```
3
4
```

but the function outputs

```
3
3
```

When I change the declaration of `h` to be

```
HonorStudent h = HonorStudent();
```

the programs outputs what I initially expected. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is called slicing. After `Student h = HonorStudent();`, `h` is just a plain `Student`.

Comment: You can try `protected:` variables instead of private and see if that helps. However, It's still not a good idea to make variables that have the same name as the parent, as a general rule.

Comment: Thank you @L.F. I was aware of the concept of slicing but was unaware that slicing extended to member variables of the same name.

Comment: @Chipster I tried making the member variables both `protected` and `public`, but both still yielded the same results as above. Thank you for the advice about not having member variables with the same name as the parent, though!

Comment: Do you by chance come from a Java background?

Comment: @curiousguy yes I do. I've programmed predominately in Java and Python.

Comment: C++ syntax is different. You need to use pointers to have something similar to the semantics of Java references. **C++ class objects work like Java builtin types**: in C++ user defined types are treated as much as builtin types as possible. Java uses the same syntax for assigning (or initializing) a scalar value or a reference. There is no direct equivalent of these references in C++, but pointers come close (they can be changed and can be null).

Comment: Overriding `returnGPA()` seems conceptually wrong. You don't want make that kind of functions a customization point, and you don't have to have such useless state in base classes in proper OOP design. Why don't you start with a pure interface? Why do you put in your base class **an implementation detail that you want to inhibit in a derived class**?

Comment: "_but was unaware that slicing extended to member variables of the same name._" It does not. In fact, I have no idea what this could mean: "the concept of slicing extends to member variables for the same name"; or even "the concept of slicing extends to member variables". Slicing has to do with the copy operation (copy construction or assignment) **as defined by the member functions of the class**. Can you describe what you believed a copy constructor would do exactly?

Comment: @Chipster "_You can try protected: variables instead of private and see if that helps_" No. Just no. It does not make sense. Access control is orthogonal to name lookup (visibility of names) and has no relevance here.

Comment: @curiousguy my point is that if you need to access a data member of the parent in the child, then the member needs to be protected. It is an alternative to making a duplicate named variable and would potentially solve the issue, provided the OP got rid of the child data member. I guess I should have been more specific.

Comment: @curiousguy I only overrode `returnGPA()` because I was experimenting with the `virtual` specifier; this was not a program I intended to use anywhere (and I was aware of how redundant it was). I simply discovered this behavior and was curious as to why it occurred. I also have a rather rudimentary understanding of slicing because I have just learned about it. As per my understanding, a copy constructor copies the attributes of one instance of an object to another during assignment. How exactly does slicing use the copy constructor?

Comment: @uglygod Careful here: assignment applies to an **existing** instance; copy construction creates an instance. A constructor doesn't change an existing instance.